# Purchased/Rented movie is not played

Tags: itunes

I have purchased/rented a movie (SD) and it is not playing... I have downloaded 1GB and the alert "ready to play" does not appear. Besides this, a doubleclick opens the Quicktime window and the player icons, but the movie does not start. The correct time is displayed and when I scroll the timeline I can see the pictures, but the play-button does not start playing the movie... I have the same problem with another movie :-(

**EDIT**: I used the native Apple iTunes Store (is there any other store?!)

Comment: What service did you download the movie from or through?

Comment: @TomUnderhill I have edited my question

Comment: Amazon also offers movie rentals. Didn't want to make false assumptions!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your computers clock a day in advance.

I have seen a time-zone issue where the the movie won't play until the computers clock is set to the following day.

Give that a try.

Answer (score -1):

re-start your device, and take a try.